# React updates state to all items that are mapped

Tags: reactjs

React should be able to edit one item within the mapped array, however when selecting edit. It edits all of the items within the array. How would i be able to fix this so that i can edit for that **specific post.id**

For example

[image]

[image]

I'm not really sure how to tell react to edit a specific item, that is equivalent to the id.

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            isEditing:false
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.title]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {
        if(this.state.isEditing){
          this.setState({
            isEditing: false
          });
        }

        else{
          this.setState({
            isEditing:true
          })
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {posts, editForm, isEditing, editChange} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                        <PostItem editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.state.isEditing} removePost={this.removePost} {...post} />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}

const PostItem = ({ title, id, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange}) => {
    return(
         <div>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                {/* if else teneray operator */}
                {/* when edit is clicked all items reveal an input field when it should just be the item that has */}
                {isEditing ? (
                    <Editable editField={title} onChange={editChange}/>
                ): (
                    <div>
                        {title}
                    </div>    
                )}         
                </Typography>
                <Typography component="p">
                    {post_content}
                    <h5>
                        by: {username}</h5>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                </Typography>
                {!isEditing ? (
                    <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                ):(
                    <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                        Update
                    </Button>
                )}
                <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={removePost(id)}>
                    Remove
                </Button>

        </div>
    )




}

export default PostItem;
```

Comment: You can store the post id in the state prop `isEditing`, then pass something like `isEditing={this.state.isEditing === post.id}` to the `PostItem`?

Comment: Also why do you have `isEditing` coming from `this.props` in your `PostList`'s `render()` method? It looks like you're only using `isEditing` from state in that component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PostList.js`:

1. First setting your initial state to `{ isEditingId: null }`.

   - You're not editing any post ids now :)
2. Change `formEditing` to something like this:

   ```
   formEditing = (id) => ()=> {
     this.setState({
       isEditingId: id
     });
   }
   ```

   - This will always store a post's `id` to the `isEditingId` property (yes, I had to change `isEditing` to `isEditingId` to make it make sense)
3. When you're creating your `PostItem` mapping, instead of using `isEditing={this.state.isEditing}`, now check if `post.id` is equal to the post id stored in `isEditingId` with this: `isEditing={this.state.isEditingId === post.id}`.

   - This will make sure `isEditing` is still passed to `PostItem.js` as a boolean, indicating whether that post is being edited or not.

In `PostItem.js`:

1. You're already passing the post's `id` in `editForm` back to `PostList` when you click the "Edit" button, which is great.
2. Now change your `onClick` handler of your "Update" button to `onClick={editForm(null)}`.

   - With this change, you should now have `isEditing` equal to `null` in `PostList.js`, so you should see no `Editable` elements.

Hope this works for ya :) It was a bit hard to test since you didn't include your `Editable` file, but hopefully the explanation above helps at least get you on the right track.

Comment: ok i will try this out. I will accept after i got it working thanks for the feedback and the assistance.

Comment: Thank you for walkthrough explanation, i followed each step with ease. This was a straightforward explanation. Really appreciate it. This works.

Comment: Happy to hear it :D